# Wordpress Category Pages - White Screen of Death

Tags: php, wordpress

Really strange thing happened:

The white screen of death came onto one of our Wordpress sites. The screen only shows on category pages. Here's a sample: http://momprepares.com/category/preparedness/

Here's what I've tried to fix the problem:

- Restored wp-includes file.
- Disabled ALL plugins.

I can't think of anything that's been changed aside from some minor stylings in the style.css file. Also, we made a custom widget and added that to the functions.php file.

I also tried disabling the widget in functions.php and the problem persists. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: No errors that I can see. Also, the HTML shows the end </html> tag so no fatal errors I can think of.

Comment: HTML display in view source???

Comment: It just shows the basic HTML - empty head, empty body.

Comment: Add error reporting in index.php file

Comment: added and just removed it. No errors show up on the category page. Strange.

Comment: echo "hello world"; chk r u getting this? Ist in index than in category

Comment: Yup. Shows up in both. Removed now.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem. We're using a Genesis theme and it was lacking a category.php file in it. Added a category.php file with the code and it worked out.